# Adding style to untagged text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have html that I can't change (as its coming from a clients database)
something like below. as you can see it is not wrapped in a tag, and I can't select the div, as I only want to target stuff under the sub_header (if it's present) with white-space:pre-line;

```
<span class="sub_header">Example:</span>
<br/>
Some text
That I need to wrap with white-space:pre-line;
As it displays on one line in html
all the way done to the div
</div>
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Does the text need to be different than everything else?  You could try defining a `body { //css rules for text}` and then redefining other text either with classes or inline css.

Comment: where is the opening `<div>` tag?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div.container').css('white-space', 'pre-line');
$('div.container span.sub_header').css('white-space', 'normal');
```

That code should apply the CSS to the parent div (which I assumed has a class of `container` but change it to whatever) but not the child span.  There are more elegant ways to do it (get inner content, exclude the `span`, then wrap it in another div styled as you need) but this will do in a jiffy assuming they are all in this format.

Answer (score 0):

looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/pKyG7/4/

```
<div>
    <span class="sub_header">Example:</span><br/>
<div style="font:arial; font-size:26px; white-space:pre-line;">Some text
That I need to wrap with white-space:pre-line;
As it displays on one line in html
    all the way done to the div.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP said he can't select a `div` which assumes he can't wrap it.

Comment: maybe I am misunderstanding. If the css is something he can't change, surely he can change what is actually written in the HTML page?

Comment: Not true.  Perhaps he's pulling it from a data base or other predefined markup.

Comment: He says in his question he is pulling this HTML from a client's database so he cannot change the markup.  However that doesn't mean he can't modify the DOM and CSS properties after the fact once the HTML has been rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery solution: http://jsfiddle.net/9PzeS/

```
$($('.sub_header + br')[0].nextSibling).wrap('<span style="white-space:pre-line"></span>');
```

Not sure if it's ideal and needs some error handling, but it seems to work.

Edit - Slightly more readable version:

```
var textNode = $('.sub_header + br')[0].nextSibling;
$(textNode).wrap('<span style="white-space:pre-line"></span>');
```

`$('.sub_header + br')[0]` selects the `br` tag in your example and gets the dom node. `nextSibling` is a vanilla js property that selects the next sibling, including text nodes.

I then wrap that with a `span` with the correct style.